# firebase hosted react app returns "you need to enable JavaScript to run this app"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, express, web

I have a web app made with react which is hosted via firebase hosting, and a backend server using express hosted on cloud functions.

Website: https://studyi.co/

The landing, login and signup pages work as expected, but on any route with /app/{route} (e.g /app/dashboard), a blank page is returned and the request returns "you need to enable javascript to run this app"

Everything here works on dev server, where the react website was started with npm start, and communicating to cloud functions by firebase.

Any idea why?

```
//routes.js
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import('../pages/Dashboard'))
const Tasks = lazy(() => import('../pages/Tasks'))

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/dashboard', // the url
    component: Dashboard, // view rendered
  },
  {
    path: '/tasks',
    component: Tasks,
  },
]
```

```
//layout.js
            <Switch>
              {routes.map((route, i) => {
                return route.component ? (
                  <Route
                    key={i}
                    exact={true}
                    path={`/app${route.path}`}
                    render={(props) => <route.component {...props} />}
                  />
                ) : null
              })}
              <Route component={Page404} />
            </Switch>
```

```
//app.js
export const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: C, ...props }) => {
    const { user } = useAuth() //useAuth is linked to firebase authStateObserver
  return (
      <Route
          {...props}
          render={routeProps =>
              user ? <C {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect excat to="/login" />
          }
      />
  )
}

const UnauthenticatedRoute = ({ component: C, ...props }) => {
  const { user } = useAuth()
  return (
      <Route
          {...props}
          render={routeProps =>
              !user ? <C {...routeProps} /> : <Redirect excat to="/app/dashboard" />
          }
      />
  )
}

<UnauthenticatedRoute excat path="/create-account" component={CreateAccount} />
<AuthenticatedRoute path="/app" component={Layout} />
<Route excat path="/" component={LandingPage} />
```

[image]

[image: Blank Page Returned from /app/about (This should just render 2 lines of text)]

I am new to web deelopment, let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: "Any idea why?" - without seeing any code ... no

Comment: why only route /app/{route}? How about moving to /app2/{route}

Comment: Added snippets of relevant code @Bravo

Comment: What you are seeing in the preview is React's index.html page. This is normal - even for pages that are working. The fact that you see a blank page instead of "You need to enable Javascript to run this app" in your browser page means javascript is enabled and is working - React's javascript code removed the "You need to..." message - so the page is blank. Your bug is that the component is not rendering. Stop looking at your network tab (it is normal). Look at your console for error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by removing "homepage": "." in package.json